# WCF generic type resolver in service hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

My question is rather theoretical, sorry for the long prologue

I'm working on a framework that has a client part and a service part. The client communicates with a WCF service and the service broadcasts the messages from one client to the others (the messages contain **Operations**). The point is that if someone wants to make use of it, he creates his **own Operation type** and implements the component that knows what to do with it (a **Transformator**) and gives this to the service and the client side manager which will basically handle the communication and use the user-implemented Transformators to do the necessary modifications (if you are interested it's basically a c# implementation of the system [described here](http://www.waveprotocol.org/whitepapers/operational-transform)).

Now my problem is, if I want to be able to create my own Operation types (which are the DataContracts), I cannot rely on KnownTypes, because that way it wouldn't be extensible without recompiling the framework source which would make it utterly useless as a framework. Looking for a solution, I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598929.aspx) that provides a solution using a Generic Resolver, that can resolve all types in the calling assembly and the referenced assemblies as well. Now this is the part where I got a bit lost.

On the client side (if I'm trying to make use of this framework) I simply use the generic resolver to resolve the types in the referenced assemblies that contain my own Operation types. If I host the service in a separate application (which I do at the moment for testing) the process is symmetrical. But what happens if I want to host the service on IIS. How would you feed the user defined types to the service in this scenario.

The only thing I could come up with so far, is to create a new project, create a subclass of the service class, reference the assemblies with the user defined Operations and use the generic resolver. Is there any cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Managed Extensibility Framework ([MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) which is meant for this sort of composing your application from pluggable parts.

You mark which parts your application needs resolved (Imports) and you create parts that can resolve these interfaces (Exports). MEF will do the discovery for you and compose the application.